# Is there a command parameter to specify the path for rz

Tags: linux, ssh, zmodem

I use `rz` command in a ssh client to upload some files to my remote app server A. If I log in remote server A and currently am in path `/home/xxx/`. I want to upload a file to under path '/home/xxx/work'.So for `rz`command, is there a command parameter to specify the A's a path where the uploaded file will be put?

Comment: Not according to the man page.  You can just change directory before running `rz`, maybe?

Comment: the only method?

Answer (score 0):

Use a compound command on the remote side:

```
ssh foo@bar "cd work && rz  ..."
```

Comment: OK, I feel I do not mean this.. I do not want to use cd command to go into the goal dir. I mean using the relative commands for rz

Comment: @AndrewGong: Well if you have a different solution, go ahead and use it.  But I think this is the way.